# Getting actual InvokePattern object from a list of AutomationPattern objects

Tags: c#, user-interface, design-patterns, microsoft-ui-automation

I have a list of `AutomationPattern` objects retrieved from the `AutomationElement.GetSupportedPatterns()` method. And now I need to know what kind of patterns are there, I mean is the single item `InvokePattern` or `ExpandCollapsePattern`. To be more specific let's assume we have an `AutomationPattern` object and we know that the `ProgrammaticName` property of this object is the "InvokePatternIdentifiers.Pattern" string, can I somehow get object of type `InvokePattern`?

I have implemented my own way of solving this problem using `AutomationPattern.ProgrammaticName` property and a big switch statement, is there another way to do this?

Here is my implemetation:

```
    public object GetActualAutomationPattern(AutomationElement element, AutomationPattern pattern)
    {
        switch (pattern.ProgrammaticName)
        {
            case "DockPatternIdentifiers.Pattern":
                return element.GetCurrentPattern(DockPattern.Pattern) as DockPattern;
            case "ExpandCollapsePatternIdentifiers.Pattern":
                return element.GetCurrentPattern(ExpandCollapsePattern.Pattern) as ExpandCollapsePattern;
            case "GridPatternIdentifiers.Pattern":
                return element.GetCurrentPattern(GridPattern.Pattern) as GridPattern;
            case "GridItemPatternIdentifiers.Pattern":
                return element.GetCurrentPattern(GridItemPattern.Pattern) as GridItemPattern;
            case "InvokePatternIdentifiers.Pattern":
                return element.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
            case "MultipleViewPatternIdentifiers.Pattern":
                return element.GetCurrentPattern(MultipleViewPattern.Pattern) as MultipleViewPattern;
            case "RangeValuePatternIdentifiers.Pattern":
                return element.GetCurrentPattern(RangeValuePattern.Pattern) as RangeValuePattern;
            case "ScrollPatternIdentifiers.Pattern":
                return element.GetCurrentPattern(ScrollPattern.Pattern) as ScrollPattern;
            case "ScrollItemPatternIdentifiers.Pattern":
                return element.GetCurrentPattern(ScrollItemPattern.Pattern) as ScrollItemPattern;
            case "SelectionPatternIdentifiers.Pattern":
                return element.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionPattern.Pattern) as SelectionPattern;
            case "SelectionItemPatternIdentifiers.Pattern":
                return element.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern) as SelectionItemPattern;
            case "TablePatternIdentifiers.Pattern":
                return element.GetCurrentPattern(TablePattern.Pattern) as TablePattern;
            case "TableItemPatternIdentifiers.Pattern":
                return element.GetCurrentPattern(TableItemPattern.Pattern) as TableItemPattern;
            case "TogglePatternIdentifiers.Pattern":
                return element.GetCurrentPattern(TogglePattern.Pattern) as TogglePattern;
            case "TransformPatternIdentifiers.Pattern":
                return element.GetCurrentPattern(TransformPattern.Pattern) as TransformPattern;
            case "ValuePatternIdentifiers.Pattern":
                return element.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
            case "WindowPatternIdentifiers.Pattern":
                return element.GetCurrentPattern(WindowPattern.Pattern) as WindowPattern;
            default:
                return pattern;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what your goal is with this code. Why can't you just do something like `object patternObj = element.TryGetCurrentPattern(pattern);` and then just test whether or not the type is what you want: `if (patternObj != null && patternObj is InvokePattern) {...} `

Comment: @Chaser324 thanks, this is exactly what I need, somehow to extract the actual pattern from AutomationPattern object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do something like:

```
object patternObj = element.TryGetCurrentPattern(pattern);
```

and then just test whether or not the type is what you want:

```
if (patternObj != null && patternObj is InvokePattern) {...}
```

Comment: Just officially adding this as a response rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will help you.

```
/// <summary>  
/// Gets the toggle state of an element in the target application.  
/// </summary> 
/// <param name="element">The target element.</param>  

private bool IsElementToggledOn(AutomationElement element)
{
if (element == null)
{
    // TODO: Invalid parameter error handling. 
    return false;
}

Object objPattern;
TogglePattern togPattern;
if (true == element.TryGetCurrentPattern(TogglePattern.Pattern, out objPattern))
{
    togPattern = objPattern as TogglePattern;
    return togPattern.Current.ToggleState == ToggleState.On;
}
// TODO: Object doesn't support TogglePattern error handling. 
return false;
}
```

I have taken this from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)